# Swift framework: using oc framework or static library with modulemap

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks, clang

I currently making a Swift framework, and my Swift framework depend on other oc framework and static library.

So i need to import them with modulemap.

But modulemap can only writen in abosuled path, this is very unfriendly for a team work.

I have tried to use aggregate target and write the script in build phases(script can use relative path to build module), but this cause another problem. The Swift framework product generate two modulemap, and when my project using this framework, xcode says it couldnt find the module that it generate by the aggregate target!

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i find a way to solve all the problem.
Cause Swift need modulemap to use the third party framework, i make an umbrella framework to wrap all the .a and .framework files, and make them public. Then make all .h file written in the umbrella file.